# Artifact capacity in Power BI Premium Gen 2

Tags: database, service, powerbi, business-intelligence, capacity

We are building a custom Premium Gen2 App report and would like to plan our resources according to the capacity provided.

Is it possible to determine how many artifacts and of what type (dataflow/dataset/paginated reports etc.) and size can be accommodated in a Premium Gen 2 capacity in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little bit challenging if you want to determine the exact number of artifacts and their sizes that can be accommodated in a Premium Gen2 capacity in Power BI because it depends on :

- the complexity of the artifacts
- data volumes
- the refresh frequencies
- the user concurrency

As far as I know, Microsoft didn't provide specific documentation on the maximum number of artifacts that can be accommodated.

I recommend the following :
**Capacity Metrics:** You can use the monitor of the capacity metrics which is provided by Power BI to help you understand the resource utilization and performance of the Premium Gen2 capacity. Those metrics include the dataset refresh duration, the memory usage, and the query duration.

**Artifact Complexity**: For example the number of visuals, complex calculations, and data model size

**Concurrent Users**: Users who are accessing/interacting with the artifacts can have an impact on the capacity utilization.

**Refresh Frequencies**: the frequency and load of dataset refreshes

**Testing and Optimization**: I highly recommend load testing and optimization on a sample of artifacts to understand the resource consumption patterns. It can help you estimate the resource requirements for your specific use case.